# Считать данные из CMD

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Добрый день, у меня вопрос, есть ли возможность считывания данных из командной строки без использования

```
RedirectStandardError = true;
RedirectStandardInput = true;
RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

ибо в такой ситуации не доступна пользовательская оболочка.
Задача определить определено состояние соединения при старте путем считывания вывода

```
ValueCommandLine.StatusRunTelnet = true;
CommandLine.BasicMethods.MaxWindowsTelnet();
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.Arguments = WCF_Client.ValueCommandLine.IP;
Info.FileName = "telnet.exe";
Info.UseShellExecute = true;
Info.CreateNoWindow = false;
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process pTelnet = new Process();
pTelnet.StartInfo = Info;
pTelnet.Start();
```

но с возможностью дальнейшие работы пользователя с данным приложением

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы делаете, и чего именно вы хотите добиться. Приведите, пожалуйста, текущий код.

Comment: Какбы, вызывать телнет из нескриптовой программы (и перенаправлять на него stdio ) - неверный путь. Верный - использовать библиотеку с поддержкой телнета.
Более того, телнет (классический) небезопасен. Уж лучше ssh. А для него есть libssh.

Comment: @PashaPash Пожалуйста, поясните подробнее. Без использования чего необходимо читать данные из командной строки? Кому (чему) должна быть доступна оболочка? Состояние какого соединения требуется проверять? С каким приложением должен работать пользователь с вашим или с telnet?

Comment: @Cerbo вопрос не мой. но суть вопроса - это не просто перенаправить stdin/stdout стороннего приложения, а сделать это недеструктивно - чтобы при этом родной вывод в консоль от целевого приложения не пострадал. т.е. это вопрос "как сделать сниффер для существующего консольного приложения". Лично мне в голову приходят только варианты с приложением-оберткой, что, хоть и будет работать, но не кажется мне красивым решением. Впрочем, полноценный ответ с оберткой я бы плюсанул :) Награду поставил чисто из любопытства.

Comment: @PashaPash Вопрос интересный, я предлагаю вам задать его самому, а с этого снять награду чтобы закрыть. Либо перепешите этот по-нормальному.

Comment: Эм.. А зачем надо перехватывать ввод?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вам нужно получить оутпут при работе с телнетом. Мне кажется вы пытаетесь решить данную задачу не верным путем. Telnet, это протокол, а раз это протокол, то вы в принципе можете сами реализовать с ним общение, а значит и получать оутпут как вам угодно. Например вот так:

```
// создание подключение где hostname: имя хоста, 23 - номер порта
TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection("hostname", 23);

// логин, с 100мс таймаутом
string s = tc.Login("root", "rootpassword",100);
// показываем оутпут
Console.Write(s);

// оуптут должен оканчиваться $ или > иначе ошибка подключения
string prompt = s.TrimEnd();
prompt = s.Substring(prompt.Length -1,1);
if (prompt != "$" && prompt != ">" )
    throw new Exception("Connection failed");

prompt = "";

// цикл обработки подключения
while (tc.IsConnected && prompt.Trim() != "exit" )
{
    // отображение оутпута
    Console.Write(tc.Read());

    // отправка команды на сервер
    prompt = Console.ReadLine();
    tc.WriteLine(prompt);

    // отображение ответа сервера
    Console.Write(tc.Read());
}

Console.WriteLine("***DISCONNECTED");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Код клиента:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MinimalisticTelnet
{
    enum Verbs {
        WILL = 251,
        WONT = 252,
        DO = 253,
        DONT = 254,
        IAC = 255
    }

    enum Options
    {
        SGA = 3
    }

    class TelnetConnection
    {
        TcpClient tcpSocket;

        int TimeOutMs = 100;

        public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port)
        {
            tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);

        }

        public string Login(string Username,string Password,int LoginTimeOutMs)
        {
            int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
            TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;
            string s = Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
               throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no login prompt");
            WriteLine(Username);

            s += Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no password prompt");
            WriteLine(Password);

            s += Read();
            TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
            return s;
        }

        public void WriteLine(string cmd)
        {
            Write(cmd + "\n");
        }

        public void Write(string cmd)
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
            byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF","\0xFF\0xFF"));
            tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                ParseTelnet(sb);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
            } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
        }

        void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                switch (input)
                {
                    case -1 :
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                        // interpret as command
                        int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputverb == -1) break;
                        switch (inputverb)
                        {
                            case (int)Verbs.IAC: 
                                //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                                sb.Append(inputverb);
                                break;
                            case (int)Verbs.DO: 
                            case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                            case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                            case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                                // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                                int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                                if (inputoption == -1) break;
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                                if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA )
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL:(byte)Verbs.DO); 
                                else
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT); 
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append( (char)input );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это, по сути, ответ на упоминание telnet.exe в теле вопроса. А если бы там бы не telnet.exe, а myconsoleapp.exe?

Comment: Так у автора проблема с telnet, или ему нужно универсальное решение для любых консольных приложений?

Comment: у автора проблема непонятно с чем - может быть ему и телнет не нужен - просто текст надо по сети отправить. просто вопрос сформулирован так, что из гугла на него будут приходить те, кому надо отсниффить данные из консоли. и я не уверен, что им будет полезен ответ про телнет (хотя проблему автора он скорее всего решит)

Comment: Ну в примере автор пытается использовать именно telnet, так что предлагаю подождать реакцию автора, а то универсальный солюшен вот прям так с ходу я не предложу :)

Answer (score 5):

Задачу можно попробовать решить хакерским способом. Гарантии не даю потому как не проверял.

В исходном процессе делаем следующее:

1. Создаем [именованый глобальный блок памяти](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx) с заранее известным именем, например `RobData`. Размер это блока должен быть минимум 12 байтов: 4 байта для PID`а исходного процесса и 8 байтов для хендла потока. Пишем в этот блок PID исходного процесса.
2. Создаем объект именованного события также с заранее изветсным именем, например `RobNotify`.
3. С помощью [внедрения DLL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/73324/) подмапываем предварительно подготовленную хитрую DLL (о ней ниже).
4. Ждем наступления события `RobNotify`
5. Вычитываем хендл пайпа стандартного потока и пользуем его [как обычно](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx), но не забываем что пайп состоит из [двух хендлов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx) и у нас в распоряжении хендл для отправляющей стороны.

В хитрой DLL в `DllMain` по `DLL_PROCCESS_ATTACH` должно быть примерно следующее:

```cpp
    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE, DWORD reason, LPVOID)
    {
        switch(reason)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            STARTUPINFO info = {0};
            GetStartupInfo(&info);

            DWORD target_pid = 0;

            // открываем блок памяти "RobData" (сопсобом из п. 1)
            // и вычитываем из него PID исходного процесса в target_pid

            HANDLE target_process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, target_pid);
            HANDLE target_pipe   ;

            DublicateHandle // клонируем хендл пайпа в исходный процесс
            (
                  GetCurrentProcess()
               ,  info.hStdOutput     // хендл пайпа для стандартного вывода
               ,  target_process
               , &target_pipe
               ,  0
               ,  TRUE
               ,  DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS
            );

            // записываем клонированный target_pipe в "RobData"

            HANDLE notify = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, _T("SpyNotify"));
            SetEvent(notify);

            CloseHandle(notify);
            CloseHandle(target_process);                
            // закрываем глобальную память "RobData"
        }
        break;

        // обрабатываем другие события
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
```

Да, и еще нужно решить все вопросы с правами доступа - их там много. Вполне допускаю что пайп стандартного потока какой-нибудь шибко закалдованный и клонированию не поддается или с правами засада, вообщем проверять надо.

Comment: Интересный вариант, к слову)